# Mule ActiveMQ Connector does not reconnect to Amazon MQ Load Balancer

Tags: activemq-classic, mulesoft, amazon-mq

We are in the process of migrating our message queues from an on prem solution to Amazon MQ. Our Mulesoft applications with queue listeners are unable to reconnect to the Amazon MQ load balancer URLs after weekly maintenance restarts. We did not have this problem with the on-prem ActiveMQ solution.

```xml
<jms:listener doc:name="Listener" destination="${queue.destination}" config-ref="JMS_CONFIG"/>

<jms:config name="JMS_CONFIG" doc:name="JMS Config">
    <jms:active-mq-connection username="${queue.user.name}" password="${queue.password}">
        <reconnection >
                <reconnect-forever blocking="false" frequency="15000"/>
        </reconnection>
        <jms:factory-configuration brokerUrl="${jms.broker.url}" />
    </jms:active-mq-connection>
</jms:config>

<jms.connector.version>1.7.1</jms.connector.version>
<!-- Tested version 1.7.3 as well. -->
```

Doesn't work:

```
jms.broker.url=ssl://broker-name.domain.net:61617
```

Work around:

```
jms.broker.url=failover:(ssl://worker-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:61617,ssl://worker-2.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:61617)
```

**Is there a way to get the load balancer url working?** We would prefer to have the traffic balanced between the two Amazon MQ workers.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors from your Mulesoft applications? Working around the issue using the `failover` url with the workers means that the the reconnection is delegated to the ActiveMQ JMS client implementation instead of Mulesoft. This indicates the problem is with Mulesoft's reconnection functionality somehow. Have you tried using `jms.broker.url=failover:(ssl://broker-name.domain.net:61617)`?

Comment: Hello @JustinBertram this was a helpful comment. Thank you. We had tried the load balancer previously with failover I believe but with a different configuration. This was successful as well. jms.broker.url=failover:(ssl://broker-name.domain.net:61617) This solves the problem of the traffic not being load balanced. Can you elaborate on "using the failover url with the workers means that the the reconnection is delegated to the ActiveMQ JMS client implementation instead of Mulesoft" or recommend a resource to learn more?

Comment: If you would consider submitting this as an answer I would mark this resolved because you answered my question "Is there a way to get the load balancer url working?" but I am still interested in understanding why it does not reconnect without failover.

Comment: The ActiveMQ JMS client implementation has a built-in ability to deal with connection failures and retry the connection so that the actual application is effectively shielded from any exceptions. This is done via the `failover` url. Lots of different JMS clients have this kind of functionality, but not all of them so integration frameworks (e.g. Mule, Camel, Spring, etc.) implement *their own* mechanisms to deal with connection failures and reconnection. In your case it looks like the Mule reconnection isn't working, but the ActiveMQ JMS client reconnection is. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working around the issue using the `failover` url with the workers means that the the reconnection is delegated to the ActiveMQ JMS client implementation instead of Mulesoft. This indicates the problem is with Mulesoft's reconnection functionality somehow. Try using `jms.broker.url=failover:(ssl://broker-name.domain.net:61617)`. That will be a better workaround as it will use the Amazon MQ load-balancer.